# Repeat a template in Jasper conditionally

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a requirement where I am arranging a large number of responses(text) in form of predefined templates. Depending on the text size, the boxes are allotted to the response. There are three sizes for the boxes. These boxes are then arranged in to defined 10-15 templates.

Since I do not have rights to post image, I am unable to show them here. Hope the idea is conveyed.

I would be displaying the responses in the best matched template. so the final page would be like 5 instances of Template1 followed by two instances of Template3 etc. 
Is there any way I can achieve the same in Jasper reports or may be some other tool by which the same can be done to export this to PDF format.

Comment: `Since I do not have rights to post image, I am unable to show them here` - you can post the external link, I'll attach image to your post

Comment: You can use subreport in main report or you can use dynamic jasper.